# Assert statement with char values

Tags: java, char, assert, assertion

I am trying to write an assertion statement to check and see if the users letter entered is between A and Z. This is the code I have:

```
assert((letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') || (letter >= 'A' && letter <= "Z")):"The letter you entered was incorrect";
```

I am getting a

**Bad operand type for binary operator '<='**

error.

Any help or tips would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean `'Z'`, not `"Z"`.

They are not the same: the first is a char literal, the second is a string literal. Comparison operators are not defined for Strings, or reference types in general.

Comment: Thank you, silly mistake I must have missed. I have not slept in about 2 days. Thank you for the extra set of eyes!